# Registering AJAX callback function that is part of a class without instantiating the class in function.php

Tags: ajax, globals

I'm not even sure if this is possible. But nevertheless I thought of asking. I'm in habit of wrapping/grouping AJAX calls for a particular need within a class. See below.

```
class my_class {
    function __construct() {
        $this->hooks();
    }

    function hooks() {
        add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', array($this, 'my_action_callback'));
    }

    function my_action_callback() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now in order for the AJAX callback to work, I must add the following to `functions.php` (without wrapping it inside any function) to instantiate the class and make the callback work.

```
$my_class = new my_class;
```

This adds `$my_class` to the `global` namespace. Something that I would like to avoid. Any idea on how I can register the AJAX callback function without instantiating the class in `functions.php`?

Comment: @Rarst's answer is correct, but why do you want your class name to not be in the global namespace?

Comment: @AndrewBartel Helps avoid variable conflicts. I can always use `$my_class = new my_class;` within a function and be sure that scope of `$my_class` remains within the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using class which needs an instance of, you have to create that instance *somewhere*. Currently WP has no designated convention for something like that.

Common practice is to use static methods, so your hook becomes `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', array(__CLASS__, 'my_action_callback'));`.

Comment: Where does the hook go? Does it go inside of the construct in the class or outside of the class? Doesn't appear to be working for me.

Comment: @John if outside replace `__CLASS__` with actual class name as string. If you need to use construct you have to create object with `new`. This is more of PHP stuff than WordPress.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely is more of PHP stuff, but I was looking for an answer in WP context. Moving the hook outside of the class was first thing I did earlier. But my bad, I was missing the quotes around the class to treat it as a string. I need some coffee now. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a class that I use to automatically create ajax callbacks from methods in the class. It acts almost like a router.

```
class AjaxEndpoint {
    //Loop through all functions and add them as ajax actions
    public function registerActions() {
        foreach ( get_class_methods( $this ) as $method_name ) {
            if ( $method_name !== 'registerActions' ) {
                add_action( "wp_ajax_".$method_name, array( $this, $method_name ) );
                //add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_".$method_name, array( $this, $method_name ) );
            }
        }
    }

}
```